# Xampp localhost cannot run in chrome but it can run in firefox

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

I can run phpmyadmin in firefox, but why it cannot run in google chrome?
Also all my php file can run in firefox but not in google chrome.
Who knows?Thanks

Comment: PHP is a server-side technology. The browser should be irrelevant. What do you mean by "cannot run in google chrome"?

Comment: Chrome has issues with `localhost` there are fixes documented but they seem to change with each version of Chrome. Do a Google on `chrome localhost` you will find a pile of info

Comment: I run using localhost but it only can run in firefox but not in chrome @Chris

Comment: What happens when you try to navigate to the localhost URL in Chrome?

Comment: Oh, okay I'll try to google that because this happen after my update on google chrome. @RiggsFolly

Comment: The webpage at http://localhost:6666/phpmyadmin/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. <- this is the error @Chris but as i said, in firefox it can successfully run

Comment: The webpage at localhost:6666/phpmyadmin might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.  @Chris

Comment: @miorfarhan, does the same thing happen if you navigate to http://127.0.0.1:6666/phpmyadmin/?

Comment: ya the same thing happen.i dont know why @Chris